# Sprite-Kit: How to visualize an SKFieldNode

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, sknode, skfieldnode

I am currently working on a magnetic field within my Sprite Kit game. Here's the initialization code:

```
    private func initMagneticField(_ object: TileMapObjectMagneticField) {
        let field = SKFieldNode.magneticField()
        field.strength = 0.75
        field.position = object.location
        field.region = SKRegion(size: CGSize(width: 320.0, height: 320.0))
        field.categoryBitMask = Globals.Categories.magneticField.rawValue
        stage?.addChild(field)
    }
```

The magnetic field works so far, but I am unsure how to position the region property of the `SKFieldNode` object.

Switching on physical visualisation does not show up the `region: SKRegion` nor the field node itself and the `region property` has neither `size` nor `position` properties:

```
self.skView.showsPhysics = true
```

How to you visualise the field itself or at least the `region property` for debugging purposes ?

Comment: @0x141E: Cool - thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a child: `field.addChild(SKSpriteNode(color:SKColor.red, size:CGSize(width: 320.0, height: 320.0)))`

Alternatively add the following to your view controller

**Swift:**

```
skView.showsFields = true
```

**ObjC:**

```
skView.showsFields = YES;
```

Comment: I get "Value of type 'SKRegion?" has no member 'size'. But I now use the size from the initialisation of the SKFieldNode and it works.

Comment: ok, I wasn't sure if you could read it or not

Comment: Btw the magnetic field attracts my space craft already before intersecting with the region. According to Apple's doc: "The physics body is located inside the field node's region (see region)." this shouldn't be the case, right? Is it maybe connected to the "charge" property of my space craft's physics body ? (The docs are a bit unclear about that..)

Comment: are you sure the ships frame is not intersecting with the region?

Comment: Yes, it's not intersecting with the red rectangle. The field starts to attract the spaceship about 100 points before intersecting the region rectangle (on all sides).

Comment: But no problem... I will find a hack around it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: 100 pts is a lot,  that is like 1/3 the width of the screen

Comment: Yes that's true.. I will report back if I found the problem. Perhaps it has somehow to do with .aspectFill or how I stretch/fit the scene. Had similar problems when I started the project some months ago.

Comment: cool. didnt know that existed